# SQL SERVER Select xml data from table where data qualifies schema collection

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, select, xsd

i want to select date from a table whcih contains an xml column (untyped), i want to verify if the data qualifies a schema collection created in the database and retrieve only those rows which qualify the schema collection. The column in the table doesnt contain and schema. Can some one help me with this !!!

Comment: @marc I think he means he has an untyped xml column, a (separate) schema, and wants the rows where the xml *does* meet the schema

Comment: Thanks AakashM for explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you have your XML in an XML column that is not associated with a schema collection and you want to fetch the rows that do match the collection.

You can do this in a loop moving one row at a time, catching the errors from the insert when the XML does not qualify.

XMLSchema:

```
create xml schema collection ItemList as '
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="item" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>'
```

Sample code moving XML from @XMLSource to @XMLTarget:

```
-- Setup the source table 
declare @XMLSource table (ID int identity, XMLCol xml)

insert into @XMLSource values ('<root><item>X</item></root>')
insert into @XMLSource values ('<root>Invalid row</root>')
insert into @XMLSource values ('<root><item>Y</item></root>')

-- Target table with XMLCol using schema ItemList
declare @XMLTarget table(XMLCol xml(ItemList))
declare @ID int

select @ID = min(ID)
from @XMLSource

-- Move one row at a time
while @ID is not null
begin
  begin try
    insert into @XMLTarget (XMLCol)
    select XMLCol
    from @XMLSource
    where ID = @ID
  end try
  begin catch
  end catch

  select @ID = min(ID)
  from @XMLSource
  where ID > @ID
end

select *
from @XMLTarget
```

Comment: Hi Mikael, Very much thanks for your response but i have a small problem with this still.. i have very huge amounts of data in my table nearly 100 million rows and this looping approach takes a lot of time .... can you suggest some other way of doing !!

Comment: @Santy - No, I do not know of any other way other then fetching the XML to a client and do the validation there. I also do not think that the loop is your main reason for this to be slow. Looping through 1 million rows takes 10 sec on my computer without checking the XML. If I check the XML as well (used the small sample in my answer) it takes 10 seconds to check 10.000 rows. You have to check every row and that is going to take a lot of time regardless of how you do it.

Comment: @Santy - Not that I know of. I guess you could write a CLR UDF that validates the XML for you and use that in a where clause. I have no idea if it will be faster or slower. It will for sure not use any index and it will be called for every row in your table that you need to validate.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131077.aspx

Comment: thanks Mikael ... i think i will go with looping instead of complicating things too much